# Elasticsearch sum_bucket aggregation to sum the values contained in resulting buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, aggregation, bucket

I have a query as follows:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "_type": "grx-ipx"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2015-09-08T15:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2015-09-08T15:10:00.000Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "inSightCustID": [
                "ASD001",
                "ZXC049"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "reportFamily": [
                "GRXoIPX",
                "LTEoIPX"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "inSightCustID",
    "fiveMinuteIn",
    "reportFamily",
    "@timestamp"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "timestamp": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "reportFamily": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "reportFamily"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "averageFiveMinute": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "fiveMinuteIn"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "distinct_timestamps": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "@timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This result of this query looks like:

```
...
"aggregations": {
        "distinct_timestamps": {
            "value": 3,
            "value_as_string": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.003Z"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1441724700000,
                    "key_as_string": "2015-09-08T15:05:00.000Z",
                    "doc_count": 10,
                    "reportFamily": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "GRXoIPX",
                                "doc_count": 5,
                                "averageFiveMinute": {
                                    "value": 1687.6
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "LTEoIPX",
                                "doc_count": 5,
                                "averageFiveMinute": {
                                    "value": 56710.6
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
...
```

What I want to do is for each bucket in the reportFamily aggregation, I want to show the sum of the averageFiveMinute values. So for instance, in the example above, I would also like to show the sum of 1687.6 and 56710.6. I want to do this for all reportFamily aggregations.

Here is what I have tried:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "_type": "grx-ipx"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "2015-09-08T15:00:00.000Z",
                  "lte": "2015-09-08T15:10:00.000Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "inSightCustID": [
                "ASD001",
                "ZXC049"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "reportFamily": [
                "GRXoIPX",
                "LTEoIPX"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "inSightCustID",
    "fiveMinuteIn",
    "reportFamily",
    "@timestamp"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "timestamp": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "reportFamily": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "reportFamily"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "averageFiveMinute": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "fiveMinuteIn"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "sum_AvgFiveMinute": {
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "reportFamily>averageFiveMinute"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "distinct_timestamps": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "@timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have added:

```
"sum_AvgFiveMinute": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "reportFamily>averageFiveMinute"
              }
            }
```

But unfortunately, this triggers an exception `Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [sum_bucket] in [sum_AvgFiveMinute]`

I expected the results to be something like:

```
...
    "aggregations": {
            "distinct_timestamps": {
                "value": 3,
                "value_as_string": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.003Z"
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": 1441724700000,
                        "key_as_string": "2015-09-08T15:05:00.000Z",
                        "doc_count": 10,
                        "reportFamily": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "GRXoIPX",
                                    "doc_count": 5,
                                    "averageFiveMinute": {
                                        "value": 1687.6
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "key": "LTEoIPX",
                                    "doc_count": 5,
                                    "averageFiveMinute": {
                                        "value": 56710.6
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "sum_AvgFiveMinute": {
                            "value": 58398.2
                        }
                    },
    ...
```

What is wrong with this query and how can I achieve the expected result?

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) is a link to the sum bucket aggregation docs.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Yeah, you need at least version 2 of ES to use that aggregation.

Comment: Aah! I just realized that I'm using: "version": "1.7.1",
"build": "b88f43f"! Cheers guys!

Comment: Any suggestions on how I might be able to achieve the desired result using my version, then? I don't have the option of upgrading, unfortunately.